# Terminal in cPanel is giving an error on launch: Error: The WebSocket handshake failed at 7:45:2. How to solve this?

Tags: websocket, terminal, bluehost

This is my error

[image]

I'm encountering an unfamiliar error involving Terminal on cPanel and Websockets. I lack familiarity with these technologies, so a patient explanation is appreciated.